# Invertible endomorphism with purely imaginary eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be real vector space and let T be an invertible endomorphism on V. Suppose that T has only purely imaginary eigenvalues, why does this imply that V is of even dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ is an endomorphism of the real vector space $V$, the degree of the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is equal to the dimension of $V$; thus if $\dim V$ is odd, this characteristic polynomial is an element of $\Bbb R[x]$ of odd degree.  Any such polynomial has at least one real root, hence $T$ has a real eigenvalue;  thus, by way of contraposition, the hypothesis that $T$ have purely imaginary eigevalues implies that $\dim V$ is even.

Comment: thank you so much @Robert ! Have a nice day.

Comment: @asma:  you are most welcome my friend, and thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!